# *get your sh–t together*

Tags: phrases

In a forum thread, someone posted a video of a guy throwing a racoon down the stairs because the racoon was fighting with his dog (named Toaster).

One user commented:

> Get your shit together Toaster.

What does that mean?

Comment: It's basically the same as [_get your act together_](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/british/get-your-act-together).

Comment: see http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/shit-tyrone-get-it-together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“Get your shit together” basically means “get better organized”. Here, *shit* means *stuff*, undifferentiated things, either in the sense of physical belongings or in a more abstract sense of someone's actions. For a dog in a fight (or for a human for that matter), this is an encouragement to the dog to be more coordinated, to demonstrate more skill, to not let himself be beaten due to clumsiness.

You probably know this already, but this is strongly on the informal and vulgar side.